# Question involving orthogonal matrix and congruent matrices $P^{t}AP=I$

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, bilinear-form, orthogonal-matrices

Suppose $A$ is a real, symmetric, positive matrix, s.t. $P^{t}AP=I$ for some congruention matrix $P$.
Prove that $\forall Q\in M_{n}(\mathbb R), Q^{t}AQ=I\iff Q=PU$, where $U$ is orthogonal.

I can't work out how to approach this (the right-to-left, mostly), is this a polar decomposition - can I show that $P$ is symmetric? I can use the fact that $A$ is symmetric to apply unitary diagonalization: $U^{t}AU=D$, but then I'm stuck with a positive $D$... it seems rather easy but I can't come up with the exact arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R = Q^{-1}.$ Then $A = R^T R$ and $P^T R^T R P = I.$ What does that say about $RP \; \; ?$

Comment: it says for any $Q$, how can you state that $Q$ is invertible?

Comment: If the rank of $Q$ is less than full, what about the rank of $Q^T A Q \; \; ?$

Comment: your'e right... so $Q^{t}AQ=I$ if assumed to be true is also a congruention? not similarity? either case $Q$ has a full rank